# Why is my rails if / else getting a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, mechanize, nomethoderror

I am using Mechanize to scrape data off of KBB.com, my app takes a url and then uses Mechanize to go through the individual pages and find the price for the given url. There are a number of different pages that a url can lead to and my app needs to be able to figure out which page it has landed on. I am currently using an if / else statement to direct the logic but I am running into a problem that I seemingly cannot debug.

When my app arrives at the if / else statement and checks the condition:

```
if agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style")
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `link_with' for nil:NilClass)
```

I tried to debug this by using:

```
 debugger if agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").nil?
```

but that gives me the same error as above, only this time it says the debugger code is the source of the problem.

How do I debug this? Or what is a better way to code this so that my app does not hit this exception?

Here's the code:

```
def kbb_value(url)
agent = Mechanize.new

# rescue bad urls
begin
  page = agent.get(url)
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
  begin
    agent.cookie_jar.clear!
    page = agent.get(url.sub('styles', 'categories'))
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    page = 'http://www.kbb.com/acura/rsx/2002-acura-rsx/styles/?intent=buy-used'
  end
end  


# kbb.com has cookie problems - solution is to clear cookies after every request

agent.cookie_jar.clear!

# program determines which starting page it is on via if / else
debugger if agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").nil?
if agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style")
  agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").click

  # if the page allows additional options - skip that page 

  if agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type")
    agent.cookie_jar.clear!
    agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type").click
  end  

elsif agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type")
  agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type").click
else
  agent.page.link_with(:href => /bodystyle/).click
  agent.cookie_jar.clear!
  agent.page.link_with(:text => 'Choose this style').click
  agent.cookie_jar.clear!
  agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type").click
end   

 # Get the 'Good' car price from kbb.com

agent.cookie_jar.clear!
agent.page.links_with(:text => "Get used car price")[2].click

# instead of getting the 'retail' value, substitute in 'private-party' in the url. Then get that page and grab the kbb value.

agent.cookie_jar.clear!
agent.get(agent.page.uri.to_s.sub('retail', 'private-party'))
@kbb_value = agent.page.at('.selected .value').text.delete('$')
end
```

Comment: What's agent.page? Or, more accurately, why are you setting page to a value then never using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with:

```
agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style") rescue debugger
```

It seems that page is nil

Comment: This along with deleting all references to the variable 'page' fixed my problem. My debugger never came up though..odd.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be one of two things:

- I've never used mechanize, but you're assigning the result to a variable called `page`, not `agent.page`.  Try changing it to compare against `page.links_with`, rather than `agent.page.links_with`, which may be null.
- Ruby has block variable scope, and any variable that is defined within a block will not exist outside of it.  You're assigning your page inside the begin (which, I believe, is a block scope).  Try changing it so you define page **outside** of the scope (as nil), and then just assign the value within the `begin/rescue`.

**Code Fix Examples:**

```
# Assign the page variable outside of the scope
page = nil
begin
  page = agent.get(url)
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
  begin
    agent.cookie_jar.clear!
    page = agent.get(url.sub('styles', 'categories'))
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    page = 'http://www.kbb.com/acura/rsx/2002-acura-rsx/styles/?intent=buy-used'
  end
end

# Check the "page" variable
debugger if page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").nil?
```

*Note: It's been a while since I've used Ruby, and forever since I've used Mechanize.  Give these a shot, hope they help.*

Comment: Really solid answer. Thanks! I had no idea about block scope.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because page wasn't loaded by Mechanize.